# 'this' is empty during Mongoose middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

long time Java programmer here trying to figure out Node.js

I am trying to cascade a delete to child objects using the pre middleware, but no child delete is happening, while the parent deletes without a hitch. Leaving my database full of sad orphans. When I started logging to the console I see that the reference to 'this' is empty. For most cases this seems to be a problem of using ==> to create the function, but I am not doing so:

GameSession(parent):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TimeLineEvent = require('../models/timelineevent');

//Define a schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var GameSessionSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    gameMasterId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'GameMaster', required: true},
});

GameSessionSchema.pre('findOneAndDelete', function(next) {
    console.log('GameSessionSchema.pre findOneAndDelete this ='+this);
    console.log('GameSessionSchema.pre findOneAndDelete id ='+this._id);
    TimeLineEvent.deleteMany({gameSessionId: this._id}).exec();
    next();
});

//Export function to create "SomeModel" model class
module.exports = mongoose.model('GameSessionModel', GameSessionSchema );
```

TimeLineEvent(child):

```
//Require Mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Define a schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TimeLineEventSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    gameSessionId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'GameSession', required: true},
    time: {type: Number, required: true},
    nextAction: {type: Number}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('TimeLineEventModel', TimeLineEventSchema );
```

This is what the console shows when the pre method is called:

```
GameSessionSchema.pre findOneAndDelete this =[object Object]
GameSessionSchema.pre findOneAndDelete id =undefined
```

Can you see what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be?

Comment: I expect it to be a GameSession object. The one that findOneAndDelete was called on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware): "In query middleware functions, `this` refers to the query."

If you use `console.log(this)` you will be able to view the full Query object. You might find `this.model` references what you need.

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me in the right direction. I switched from 'findOneAndDelete' to 'deleteOne', and then get the object id: 'this.getQuery()['_id']'

Comment: this._conditions._id worked fro me,
trying to check output of this helped me https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7134